# Workflow in odoo

Tags: odoo, workflow, odoo-8

I want to modify workflow sales.order using Workflow editor. 
I created activities and transitions between them.
After click on button user must transmit to another activity(workflow state) but nothing change. 
Next activity in action block has such python action:

```
write('state': 'maket_completed')
```

I tried to use server action with set same state sales.order
sales.order state field not changed.
I read for it docs and "Working with Odoo" and can not undestend where is my mistake.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Re-create document and all works fine.